# What diagnostics are safe to run on an SSD drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, crash, data-recovery

I have a MacBook Pro (late 2010) with a Crucial RealSSD 256Gb in it; 60Gb is given to the Windows 7 x64 BootCamp partition.  I have a USB-attached 500Gb drive for (most) data.

In the last day or so, I've had a BSOD and several OS freezes (both Mac OSX 10.6.6 and Win7).  The system in both cases will boot fine (at the moment!) and then run things fine, then some time later a program will stop responding, followed shortly thereafter by the system as a whole, forcing a reboot.

This smacks to me of a storage problem.

Given that I have an SSD and not a regular magnetic HDD, what are my next steps, **in both OS'**?

I haven't seen anything pertinent in Windows' event-log.  I'm not sure of the equivalent place to look in OSX; it's never given me issue to find out.

What are my options for attempting to save my data from the SSD to another drive, given that after some small amount of time (eg half an hour), the OS stops responding?

What are the recommended next steps?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start) CD-ROM or USB stick, and clone the disk using the command [`ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) from there.